Movie about a woman and a girl sailing for the Promised Land
I watched this movie in 2007++. It's in English. It's genre is scifi I think. It's about a family searching for a Promise Land.
Not much what I remember about this:

The woman and girl are wearing rag like clothes
They travel by boat with a man (his husband) as the captain
They are looking for a Promised Land.
I guess they are in a boat for a long time because they fish for food and use some sort of water purifier for drink


If it's not Promised Land, but Dryland, then it is Waterworld (1995) starring Kevin Costner.
Some story plot:

In a future where the polar ice-caps have melted and Earth is almost entirely submerged, a mutated mariner fights starvation and outlaw "smokers," and reluctantly helps a woman and a young girl try to find Dry land. 

This is  a trailer of this movie:




Are you sure all existing copies of this movie weren't destroyed by 2007? :P

My friend runs a DVD shop. I might get lucky :D

I know I'll probably get teased for admitting this but I actually like this film!
